# VBA Summarize Monthly Data by Year

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to summarize a table with 3 years of monthly data into a year over year trend.  The products are listed in column A and months are listed in Row 1 from column B to AK. Each month is formatted as 2014/01, 2014/02.. 2017/01 etc. The values for each product are in number format. Here is an example of the table.

[image]

I would like the final summary to look like this...

[image]

I think I need to use a left function to find the first instance of a new value in row 1 (column headers) and return the column number of each new year start.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your example table is in an "example" sheet and goes down to column H, and that your result table is in a "result" sheet and starts in cell A1
try to paste this in cell B2 of your result table:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(1*LEFT(Example!$B$1:$H$1,4)=Result!B$1),Example!$B2:$H2)
```